# AngularJS - ui-grid - Column Moving - get new order of columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am implementing http://ui-grid.info/ in my application.

There is a feature of `Column Moving`, where Columns can be moved.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/217_column_moving

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview)

This is how i add columns :-

```
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ field: 'Name', displayName: 'EMPLOYEE NAME'});
$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs.push({ field: 'Age', displayName: 'AGE'});
....
```

Here is the event which fires when column is moved.

http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.moveColumns.api:PublicApi

My problem is that i want to get the `new order` of the `columns` in `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs` for saving it in db.

On Column Moving `$scope.gridOptions.columnDefs` doesn't get updated.

How to solve this?

Comment: That Plunker is very empty. Good thing is: It has no bugs:-)

Answer (score 4):

You will need to get the new order from grid state. Try get the grid state using this: (remember to add 'ui.grid.saveState' module and 'ui-grid-save-state' directive)

```
$scope.state = $scope.gridApi.saveState.save();
```

Take a look at their tutorial about grid state [here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/208_save_state)

Answer (score 0):

You can listen to the columnPositionChanged event:

gridApi.colMovable.on.columnPositionChanged(scope,function(colDef, originalPosition, newPosition){})

Check [ui-grid documentation](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.moveColumns.api:PublicApi) for more info